# Building mpijavac with ant

Tags: java, ant, mpi

I am writing a project to use mpi in a cluster for which I have to generate a jar file with `mpijavac`.

In command line I would do

```
mpijavac <List of java files>
```

I want to embed this task in an ant target. For example, if I had to build a regular jar file I would do

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean, init"
        description="compile the source ">
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build.src.dir} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build.src.dir}"/>
</target>


<jar jarfile="${jarfileName}" basedir="${build.src.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Execute"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

To get the jar, but this would compile it with javac and not mpijavac. Is there anyway I can get the jar file built with `mpijavac` using ant as my build tool